# Angular CLI's prod build fails to load when using with Yarn

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, yarnpkg

My understanding of Yarn is that it is a drop-in replacement for NPM; and that for a particular `package.json`, I will get the same `node_modules` folder whether I run `yarn install` or `npm install`.

However, there seems to be a problem.

I am using Angular CLI 1.4 for my project. When I retrieve packages by running `yarn install` and then serve using `ng serve --prod` (or run `ng build --prod` and host the `dist` folder), the build completes successfully but the site fails to load, giving an error `No provider for e!`. However, the same works when I retrieve the packages using `npm install`.

Also, both `yarn install`ed and `npm install`ed `node_modules` work fine in the `development` mode.

I saw that there is a CLI switch to change the package manager: `ng set --global packageManager=yarn`, but I don't know what it does and how it affects the build process. Also, I tried this and it didn't work.

How do I get more information about this problem or how do I fix it?

Comment: install your node_modules using npm install. you want build the project use yarn build --prod

Comment: Can you explain why? I am curious to know.

Comment: It's working correctly ?. read about yarn https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/getting-started

Comment: Not as expected. `ng build --prod` only runs the build script but `yarn build --prod` runs the pre and post build scripts too. Also, installing using `node_modules` and building via `yarn` doesn't explain the concept.

Comment: Try this: `ng build --prod --aot=false`